How to override prime-ng icon style in disabled state at icon input field
:host {
    ::ng-deep .p-inputtext {
        padding-top: 0.625rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.625rem;
        border: 0.063rem solid var(--neutral-medium-400);
        border-radius: $text-feild-border-radius;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #161616;
        font-size: 1rem;
        box-shadow: none;

        &:disabled {
            color: var(--neutral-medium-400);
        }

        &::placeholder {
            color: var(--neutral-medium-500);
        }
    }

    ::ng-deep .p-icon-field-left .p-input-icon:first-of-type,
    ::ng-deep .p-icon-field-right .p-input-icon:first-of-type {
        color: $icon-color;
    }
}

i want at the disabled state of the input field to change the color of the icon
what is the proper scss selector to do so ?

The current code looks like it should work. What results are you getting and whats the markup look like
